# Where to find changes from iphone OS 3.0 to 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

I've developed an app using the 3.1.3 SDK and I want to set the deployment target to OS 3.0.

The app uses iPod functionality which I can't test on the Simulator so my question is:

Is there somewhere I can find a list of the changes from 3.0 to 3.1.3 so I can check if anything might be broken on an OS 3.0 device?

I've looked on Apple's website obviously but can't find anything.

How do people normally test on old software releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All major changes should be present in [OS 3.0 to OS 3.1 API Diffs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/iPhone31APIDiffs/index.html)